# R: extract text after ")"

Tags: r, dplyr

A simple question but I can't find solution. In R dplyr how do I extract text after a ")" and then split it based on "/"?
my data is like this

```
    # A tibble: 3 x 2
     id Group             
  <dbl> <chr>             
1     1 (aa1) red/yellow  
2     2 (bb1) blue/yellow 
3     3 (cc1) green/orange

structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), group = c("(aa1) red/yellow", 
"(bb1) blue/yellow", "(cc1) green/orange")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I would simply like:

[image: example output]

Seems simple but I am new to r and cannot figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: i would just use `read.table(text = gsub('/', ' ', data$group))` but if you must use the tidyverse they use `tidyr::separate` for something like this

Answer (score 2):

you can use `regmatches` in combination with `regexpr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), group = c("(aa1) red/yellow","(dd1) blue/yellow","(cc1) green/orange"))
df %>% 
  mutate(x1 =  regmatches(group,regexpr("^\\(.{3}\\)",group)),
         x2 = regmatches(group,regexpr("(?<= )\\w+(?=/)",group,perl = TRUE)),
         x3 = regmatches(group,regexpr("(?<=/)\\w+$",group,perl = TRUE)))
```

output is:

```
id              group    x1    x2     x3
1  1   (aa1) red/yellow (aa1)   red yellow
2  2  (dd1) blue/yellow (dd1)  blue yellow
3  3 (cc1) green/orange (cc1) green orange
```

If you don't know how to use regular expressions [you can read this](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/regular-expressions.html), it is a helpful intro to regular expressions

Comment: thanks for this, haven't got it to work on my data but trying to learn regular expressions. Really, I just want to separate after the ")" (my real data has more than 3 characters in id column) and then, once separate split using the "/"

Comment: a.`"(?<=\\)).+$"` This will extract everything from after the first ")" until the end of the string.
b.if every new colour is seperated by a "/" **and**  each group contains the same amount of colours you can use
`df %>%
  separate(.,col = group,into = paste0("colour_",1:(str_count(df$group[1],"/")+1)),sep = "/")`

Answer (score 2):

First `separate` the values in `group`, `sep`arating them by whitespace `\\s` or `/`, then remove the parentheses in `x1` using `sub` and 'recollecting' only the alphanumerical parts `\\w+` in the replacement with backreference `\\1`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  separate(., col = "group", into = paste0("x", 1:3), sep = "\\s|/") %>%
  mutate(x1 = sub(".(\\w+).", "\\1", x1))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     id x1    x2    x3    
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1     1 aa1   red   yellow
2     2 bb1   blue  yellow
3     3 cc1   green orange
```

**EDIT**:

If your input data is more complex, as suggested in a comment, such as this:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), group = c("(aa1) red bus/yellow", 
                                                "(bb1) blue/yellow", "(cc1) green/orange apple")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                           -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

then this will work:

```
df %>%
  separate(., col = "group", into = paste0("x", 1:3), sep = "\\) |/") %>%
  mutate(x1 = sub(".(\\w+).", "\\1", x1))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     id x1    x2      x3          
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <chr>       
1     1 aa    red bus yellow      
2     2 bb    blue    yellow      
3     3 cc    green   orange apple
```

Comment: thank you for responding. I haven't got this to work on my data and I am not familiar enough with code to understand why. Ideally a solution would simply separate after ")". The issue then is that my red/yellow example might actually be multiple words (e.g. red bus/yellow truck). The consistent character is the "/". I need to separate out into two columns whatever is on the left or right of the "/", and discount whatever is the parentheses.

Comment: Please see the edit. Does this solve the issue?